# syntax error, unexpected identifier enum laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I am using LARAVEL 9. I am create enum in Enum folder and access in model. But when i am adding data i am getting this error

> syntax error, unexpected identifier "GenderEnum"

Here is my code

GenderEnum.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Enum;


enum GenderEnum:string
{
    case MALE = 'male';
    case FEMALE = 'Female';
}
```

AdminSeeder.php

```
  $data = [
        'first_name' => 'Rishab',
        'last_name' => 'goyal',
        'email' => 'RISHABGOYAL@yopmail.com',
        'mobile_number' => '123',
        'role' => '1',
        'gender' => 'male',
        'password' => '123',
        'profile_photo' => '',
    ];
    Admin::addEdit($data);
```

Admin.php (Model)

```
protected $casts = [
    'gender' => GenderEnum::class
];
```

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: did you include 'use App\Enum' in Admin.php

Comment: Php version i use 8

Comment: Yes, i have include use App\Enum

Comment: @RishabGoyal I'm having the same problem. Checked my namespace and it is correct also.

Answer (score 14):

There's nothing wrong with your code even in the namespace. The problem is your environment setup, maybe you are still running PHP `8.0` or below instead of PHP `8.1`

> Enums is a new syntax introduced in PHP 8.1, and not
> supported in older PHP versions.
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1):

Please check 'use App\Enum' namespace is imported properly

Comment: Yes it is correct

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before.
My solution is to update your PHP version to 8.1.